# Adding multiple line break in react-markdown

Tags: reactjs, strapi, react-markdown

Currently I'm using React and have content in my rich text in strapi CMS that is spaced out the way I want it in my markdown version, but as soon as I switch to preview, or view the content in my browser, the spaces go away. I have tried adding `<br/>` tags, but there was still no line breaks.

This is the content in my strapi markdown:
[image: ![image|690x273, 50%](upload://jy7Rsdurp6rq6VNB0ki4Jnc9L24.png)]

But this is the output on my webpage:
[image: ![image|690x128, 50%](upload://b4cGhjj4uOjO6uCCpXcggetnqNO.png)]

This is my current code:

```
import ReactMarkdown from "react-markdown";
import rehypeRaw from "rehype-raw";
export default function name({ posts }) {
  return (
    <>
        <div>
          {posts.Title}
        </div>
      <div>
        <ReactMarkdown children={posts.Content} rehypePlugins={[rehypeRaw]} />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Does this solve your issue? https://github.com/remarkjs/react-markdown/issues/273

Comment: @John no so I have tried adding &nbsp;  at the end of a line and \n as well but both didn't give me the output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For adding multiple line break, this should do it:**

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

import ReactMarkdown from "react-markdown";

export default function App() {
  const markdown = `hello
  \n &nbsp;
  \n &nbsp;
  \n &nbsp;
  \n &nbsp;
  \n
  world
  `;

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ReactMarkdown source={markdown} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit react-markdown basic example (forked)]

Comment: saved my day. Was struggling to add extra space. Your solution is precise.

Answer (score 7):

use [remark-breaks](https://github.com/remarkjs/remark-breaks)

and replace `\n` with `&nbsp; \n`. if one `\n` doesn't work, try adding one more

```js
import remarkBreaks from "remark-breaks";

//...

<ReactMarkdown 
  remarkPlugins={[remarkBreaks]}
  rehypePlugins={[rehypeRaw]}
  children={posts.Content.replace(/\n/gi, "&nbsp; \n")}
/>
```

Comment: this works nice with spaces but it breaks some of my other tags. `<code/>` having `&nbsp;` at the start and finish and the `<ul>` list not displaying the dots. Every `<li>` has a `<br>` in between. How to fix these?

Comment: Thanks. `<ReactMarkdown remarkPlugins={[remarkBreaks]}>{recommendation}</ReactMarkdown>` worked for me. I just needed to check my SCSS rules and make sure I wasn't doing weird stuff with `p` margins.

Comment: @Ilir change the replace to `.replace(/\n/gi, "\n &nbsp; \n")`. Won't break li and ul stuff